# Creating A Row Number column in Dataframe in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, window

INPUT CSV:

```
Series_reference,Period,Data_value,UNITS,Magnitude
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2016.06,1116.386,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2016.09,1070.874,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2016.12,1054.408,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2017.03,1010.665,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2017.06,1233.7,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2017.09,1282.436,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2017.12,1290.82,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2018.03,1412.007,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2018.06,1488.055,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2018.09,1497.678,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2018.12,1570.507,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2019.03,1393.749,Dollars,6
BDCQ.SF1AA2CA,2019.06,1517.143,Dollars,6
```

We have to add a new column with name ROW_NUM starting with 1 and incrementing with 1 on each row.

Expected OUTPUT:

```
+----------------+-------+----------+-------+---------+-------+
|Series_reference|Period |Data_value|UNITS  |Magnitude|ROW_NUM|
+----------------+-------+----------+-------+---------+-------+
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2016.06|1116.386  |Dollars|6        |1      |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2016.09|1070.874  |Dollars|6        |2      |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2016.12|1054.408  |Dollars|6        |3      |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2017.03|1010.665  |Dollars|6        |4      |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2017.06|1233.7    |Dollars|6        |5      |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2017.09|1282.436  |Dollars|6        |6      |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2017.12|1290.82   |Dollars|6        |7      |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2018.03|1412.007  |Dollars|6        |8      |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2018.06|1488.055  |Dollars|6        |9      |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2018.09|1497.678  |Dollars|6        |10     |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2018.12|1570.507  |Dollars|6        |11     |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2019.03|1393.749  |Dollars|6        |12     |
|BDCQ.SF1AA2CA   |2019.06|1517.143  |Dollars|6        |13     |
+----------------+-------+----------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum;

---- Read Dataset 
Dataset<Row> df=session.read().option("delimiter",",")
                .option("header",true)
                .option("escapeQuotes",true).csv(filepath)


---- Add ROW_NUM column with lit(1)
df=df.withColumn("ROW_NUM", lit(1));

--- Create A Windowspec object
WindowSpec winSpec =Window.orderBy("ROW_NUM").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding(),Window.currentRow());


--- Take Sum Over Window from beginning to Current Row
df=df.withColumn("ROW_NUM",sum("ROW_NUM").over(winSpec));

df.show(false) # Will give the expected answer.
```